# OpenCV Algorithm slows down without reason

Tags: opencv, stream, ueye

At the moment I am working on a project, which searches a sample in a video stream and constantly check it.
But after a while (sometimes some seconds, sometimes some minutes) it just stops working. No detecting, no video stream. 
I checked my processor, and also tried different resolutions. But it's still not working correctly.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/mat.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/// Create a flag, used for nearly everything
int flag = 0;
int i = 0;

/// BlackPixel counter
float blackPixel;

/// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
double minVal, maxVal; 
Point minLoc, maxLoc, matchLoc;

/// Punkte für drawMatch
Point middle_x, middle_y;

/// Creating picture Matrix
Mat image_input, image_template, image_display, image_object;

/// Create the result matrix
int result_cols, result_rows;

/// Test Inputs
Mat pictureTest;
Mat objectTest;



string intToString(int number) {

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();

}


void drawMatch(Mat object, Mat scene, vector<Point> match_centers)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < match_centers.size(); i++)
    {
        /// middle of template at X
        middle_x = Point((object.cols / 2) + match_centers[i].x, match_centers[i].y);

        /// middle of template at Y
        middle_y = Point(match_centers[i].x, match_centers[i].y + (object.rows / 2));

        /// Zeichnet Rechteck um Match
        rectangle(scene, Point(match_centers[i].x, match_centers[i].y), Point(match_centers[i].x + object.cols, match_centers[i].y + object.rows), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

        /// Zeigt das Ergebnis des Tracking
        namedWindow("Track", WINDOW_NORMAL);
        imshow("Track", scene);

        /// Gibt die Koordinaten des Matches im Bild an
        //putText(scene, "(" + intToString(match_centers[i].x) + "," + intToString(match_centers[i].y) + ")", Point(match_centers[i].x - 40, match_centers[i].y - 15), 1, 1, Scalar(255, 0, 0));
    }
}


vector<Point> imageComparetion(Mat object, Mat scene, int match_method, float peek_percent) {

    scene.copyTo(image_display);
    object.copyTo(image_object);

    result_cols = scene.cols - object.cols + 1;
    result_rows = scene.rows - object.rows + 1;
    Mat result(result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1);

    /// match scene with template
    matchTemplate(scene, object, result, match_method);

    ///normalize(result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
    normalize(result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());

    /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
    if (match_method == TM_SQDIFF || match_method == TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
    {
        matchLoc = minLoc;
        threshold(result, result, 0.1, 1, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    }
    else
    {
        matchLoc = maxLoc;
        threshold(result, result, 0.9, 1, THRESH_TOZERO);
    }

    vector<Point> res;
    maxVal = 1.f;

    Mat input_matrix = image_display; //webcam image into matrix
    Mat match = Mat(input_matrix.size(), input_matrix.type(), Scalar::all(0));

    while (maxVal > peek_percent) {

        minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat());

        if (maxVal > peek_percent) {

            Rect r1(Point(maxLoc.x - object.cols / 2, maxLoc.y + object.rows / 2), Point(maxLoc.x + object.cols / 2, maxLoc.y - object.rows / 2));
            rectangle(result, Point(maxLoc.x - object.cols / 2, maxLoc.y - object.rows / 2), Point(maxLoc.x + object.cols / 2, maxLoc.y + object.rows / 2), Scalar::all(0), -1);
            res.push_back(maxLoc);

        }

    }

    return res;

}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    ///open Cam
    VideoCapture cap(1);
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);

    ///Check if cam is open
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "\n Bitte Verbindung zur Kamera ueberpruefen! \n";
        return 0;
    }


    ///Read the matches template
    image_template = imread("C:/Users/Ceraxes/Pictures/glaspol.jpg");
    Mat current = imread("C:/Users/Ceraxes/Pictures/glaspol.jpg");


    cap >> image_input;


    ///find location of template in stream
    vector<Point> match_centers = imageComparetion(image_template, image_input, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, 0.3); //template, picture, matching method, treshold(peak percent)

    /// shows the found template
    drawMatch(image_template, image_input, match_centers);

    waitKey(1);

    ///build window
    namedWindow("IDS", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    Mat detect = image_input; //img_display
    Mat draw = Mat(detect.size(), detect.type(), Scalar::all(0));


    while (true) {

        cap >> detect;

        ///Show image from camera
        imshow("IDS", detect);      

        /// check every found match
        while (i < match_centers.size()) {

            ///Extract the found matches from the picture

            Rect r3(Point(match_centers[i].x, match_centers[i].y), Point(match_centers[i].x + image_template.cols, match_centers[i].y + image_template.rows));

            ///compares the camera imgage with the template
            absdiff(detect(r3), current, pictureTest);

            ///counts the differences
            blackPixel = countNonZero(pictureTest == 150);


            cout << blackPixel << "\n";

            i++;

        }

        i = 0;

        waitKey(1);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

I'm using a `IDS ueye` camera, openCV 4 und Visual Studio 2017.

Does anyone have an idea, why the algorithm slows down?

Comment: 1. Whats about memory? See in Task Manager. 2. Do you can run debug version in VS? And press "Pause" when application is hangs. So you can see in witch function or loop is working.

Comment: 1. Still got 4gb left.. So nothing special. 
2. I tested debug and the *.exe file (it's a desktop application).
When I stop the the program it says 
"Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)."

Runnig the programm with the interal webcam works without any problems. But I can't imagine why the programm stops after a while using the IDS Ueye

Comment: Are you using usb or ethernet camera? Have you installed IDS drivers?